# Using Nginx as a scalable comet server

Tags: c++, c, linux, nginx, memcached

I know how i can scale a simple nginx server horizontally and load balance them, but i was wondering if i could scale it the same way while using it with nginx_http_push_module.

What concerns me the most is how will channels created on other servers be accessible by the subscribers on other server.

Can some one point me in some direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can but....
1/ FOR THE PUBLISHER
 You should make on every server a proxy like this

```
  location /1/publish/
   {
     resolver 127.0.0.1;
     rewrite ^/([0-9])/publish.*$ /publish break;  
     proxy_pass http://chat1.attractiveworld.net;  
     proxy_redirect    default;
   }
```

- You should make this for all your servers (/[1-n]/publish
- /x/publish is your local url to publish to respect some javascript protection.
- Make a table (in share memory) or in database to know where your user are (subscriber)

2/ FOR THE SUBSCRIBER
on every server

```
   location /1/activity
   {
     rewrite ^/([0-9])/publish.*$ /activity break;
     proxy_pass      http://chat1.attractiveworld.net/activity;
     proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
     proxy_method GET;
     proxy_read_timeout 40;
     proxy_send_timeout 40;
     proxy_connect_timeout 40;

   }
```

it's the local url to receive messages.

In this way, your have one channel for one client, you don't have a share channel between two client.

Comment: thanks alot for this. can we use this somehow to share 1 channel amount more then 1 subscribers. so users can chat with users on other servers, because that is basically what i want to achieve.